# How to switch UIViews with animation within single iOS screen

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

I want to build a fairly simple app with just 1 screen. As a result, I would like two views within the same view controller.

```
View1 - appear for 5 seconds
View2 - appear during gameplay
View1 - appear for 5 seconds
View2 - appear during gameplay
And so on.
```

Though I don't know how to make this happen, I am sure this design pattern is valid.

I searched documentation but can't find definite answer.

I know apps which does this, but how, I don't know.

Is it viewcontroller.view = View1 or View2? If so, how would I make this switch with some nice animation?

I know of animations but not in this kind of case. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two views as subviews of your viewController's view:

```
[viewController.view addSubview:view1];
[viewController.view addSubview:view2];
```

Then use an animation block:

```
// the following code will replace view1 with view2 after a 5 second delay

// this ensures view2 is behind view1
[viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:view2];
[viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:view1];

// get view2 ready for the animation
view2.alpha = 0;
view2.hidden = NO;

// delay for 5 seconds before executing animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:5 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{

    //fade out
    view1.alpha = 0;

    // fade in
    view2.alpha = 1;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    // hide it after animation completes
    view1.hidden = YES;

    // bring view2 to front (even though view1 is not visible, it is still above view2)
    [viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:view2];
}];
```

to replace view1 with view2. And so on.